# Is there any css attribute that would stop any attempt of animating hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, hidden, redraw

I hid the hole container of a NivoSlider, and I can see the browser still struggling animating the independent pieces of the images (sliced up into fading divs)

Is there any css attribute (webkit?, height 0 for all the children?, etc) to eliminate all or most of the power for the browser to animate those elements?

I want to mess the animation enough just with css for it to be unable to run, only from css, without touching the javascript plugin or rendering a different page, to disable animation in mobile devices.

Thanks.

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; ?

Comment: Can post `html` , `css` , `js` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
display: none !important;
```

can't provide further answer, please give us some snippets of your code!

Comment: The question is too generic and basic. Snippet should not be needed. ANY example of animation at jQuery website or jsfiddle would be enough to test it IF you know the answer.